# Android Account Manager caching time of auth token

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I'm developing an own Authenticator for the android account manager, and i'm asking me how long the account manager caches the auth token? Or do i have to invalidate the auth token after a specified time?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually call accountManager.invalidateAuthToken, otherwise token will be stored in the cache.

> It's the responsibility of applications to invalidate auth tokens when they stop working so the AccountManager knows it needs to regenerate them.

Steps of normal using Account Manager are described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)